# Connecting a network wireless adapter to BackTrack 5 R3

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualization

I installed BackTrack 5 R3 x64 on a VMware Workstation 10 while running Windows 8 x64. I bought a Network Wireless adapter "TL-WN8200ND" and this adapter works as normal in my system.

But when I want to connect my adapter in BackTrack I get shown this message:

> A USB device is about to be unplugged from the host and connected to this virtual machine. It will first be stopped to enable safe removal. With some devices, the host may display the message "The device can now safely be removed."

If I select OK, the adapter does not work.